Is there a proper replacment for WillPopScope rather than PopScope?
I had made a chatting application but I am having problems in it's chatting screen because I am using emoji_picker_flutte package to show a emoji board,and I had implemented it such that whenever the emoji board was on the a bool varaible was true and vice varsa and if ther user uses back navigation gesture first the emoji board will disapper then if the user uses back navigation gesture again then the page will pop.
When using WillPopScope there was no issue, but recently with PopScope it dosen't, I have tried placing the whole code in onPopInvoked just as migration said with canPop set to false but it dosen't work.
I also tried using the whole code into seprate function with the return type as bool and using thet function on canPop but it failed because canPop is running all the time while that page is on while using this way the emoji board dosen't even appear and because as the emoji button is pressed and the variable turns true it immediately becomes false while everything is working normally.
bool _willpop() {
    if (_showEmoji) {
      setState(() => _showEmoji = !_showEmoji);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }


PopScope (
canPop = _willpop();
child:...
)

Other way
_willpop(bool p) {
    if (p) return;
    if (_showEmoji) {
      change();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

PopScope (
canPop: false,
onPopInvoked: (didpop) => _willpop(didpop),
child:...
)


both of the ways don't work can anyone suggest a better way for this

I found the solution, here is the solution and it works as I wanted
  bool _showEmoji = false;

  void change() => setState(() => _showEmoji = !_showEmoji);

  _willpop() {
   if (_showEmoji) change(); 
  }

  PopScope(
  canPop: !_showEmoji,
  onPopInvoked: (_) => _willpop(),
  child:...,
  ),


onPopInvoked asked for a void fn. So you did not need to return anything. _willpop() should be a void fn.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

yep I have updated it now, before i waas using ther same code as i used in Willpopscope

In the second way if p is true don't return anything. Just remove that line.
if (p) return;

Now if _showEmoji is true just reverse its value and called setState but if it is false use Navigator.pop(context) to pop
_willpop(bool p) {
    if (_showEmoji) {
      change();
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

Why your first method is not working might be because when you set _showEmoji=true, you did not called the setState(), so new PopScope widget did not build with canPop as false but still as true, which allows user to go back.
But my advice do not uses first method because this method is called when widget build, and you are calling setState() on widget build which rebuild the widget again if condition matches. If conditions are not handled properly it will cause widget to rebuild again and again.
That's why use second method, which only call when user really tries to go back , not on widget build.

So i should use the second method without setState on onPopInvoked ?
bool _willpop() {
if (_showEmoji) {
_showEmoji = !_showEmoji;
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
}

You can use second method with set state. In my answer I said not to use it for first method. Where you are calling setState inside a fn that is given to canPop and is executed evey time widget build. But onPopInvoked is a callback fn that is not affected by widget build, it is like a button. That's why said to use second method. And it's good you find a solution.
